# Justified Navbar in Bootstrap 3.2 with list items that fill 100% height?

Tags: html, css

I have created a Justified Navbar in Bootstrap 3.2 but I can't seem to get the links within the list items to display 100% height. See my JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fncage1n/2/

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified">
        <li><a href="#">Find your Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#">New Developments <span class="caret visible-xs"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Poole Road, Sunderland</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#">Buying from Inspired <span class="caret visible-xs"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Why choose Inspired?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Buying Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Incentives</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Customer Care</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#">Help to Buy <span class="caret visible-xs"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Find out if you qualify</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other schemes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: none; }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.navbar-toggle {
    margin: 10px 20px; } 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.nav-justified > li, .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-left: 1px solid #598d8d;
    float: none; }

.nav-justified > li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #598d8d; }

/* FOR HIGHLIGHTING PROBLEM ONLY */
.navbar-nav.nav-justified > li a {
    background: #660066; }

.navbar-collapse {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0; }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%; }

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    transition: 0; }

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff; }

.dropdown-menu, .follow-us .dropdown-menu {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; } 
}
```

The problem only happens when viewing at tablet size, as the text in some of the menu items span across more than 1 line. The menu items that fit on 1 line, then don't fill 100% of the Navbar height - I've highlighted the background of the links in purple so you can see it better without hovering.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong? Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fixed this on reset `.nav>li>a` padding in your media query `min-width: 768px` like this:

CSS :

```
 .nav-justified > li a, .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li a{
     padding:15px 0; 
 }
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/fncage1n/5/**